# Best practice to have multiple instances of a single fragment with different data sets in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an app that uses the same fragment for many areas, but every instance need to use a different list of custom objects and an URL to download the data if is missing.
I'm using the newInstance() pattern but I'd like to know if there's a smart way to have different behaviors using the same fragment class without creating different fragments.
Thanks